# Can I FORCE the filter button to show on my DataGridViewColumnHeader?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a C# WinForms DataGridView that by default does not (and cannot) have filtering enabled. The result is that when I display the DGV there are no filtering buttons displayed.

As opposed to using a DataTable (not an option in my case) I would like to always display a drop down button right aligned in my header cells: [image: filtering button]

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Can I force a button to be rendered?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom header cell inheriting from [`DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumnheadercell(v=vs.110).aspx). Then override its `Paint` method and draw a button on header.

First call the `base.Paint` method and then draw the button at suitable location.

To draw such button you can use `ButtonRenderer.DrawButton` and use an image for dropdown. Also you can use `ComboBoxRenderer.DrawDropDownButton` which draws a dropdown for you.

Also to show it in your grid assign an instance of your custom header cell to `HeaderCell` property of the column that you want:

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderCell = new FilterDataGridViewColumnHeader();
```

[image]

The above screenshot is created using this code:

```
public class FilterDataGridViewColumnHeader : DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell
{
    protected override void Paint(System.Drawing.Graphics graphics, System.Drawing.Rectangle clipBounds, System.Drawing.Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates dataGridViewElementState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
        base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, dataGridViewElementState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);
        ComboBoxRenderer.DrawDropDownButton(graphics, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(cellBounds.Right - 16, 4, 14, cellBounds.Height - 6), System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.ComboBoxState.Normal);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million @Reza. I was hoping to avoid the Paint method altogether but from googling I realize this might be the way to go. Thanks :-)